# Container/Structure to Initialize Based on Position

Tags: c++, initialization, containers, minimum

I have some data who's `index` is part of it's information. Therefore I'd like this information to be somehow used in the construction of the object to be placed into the container.

I'm trying to capture the smallest value with bit `index`.

```
set<int> numbers{1, 3, 5, 6, 10, 13, 24};
vector<decltype(numbers)::key_type> int_log(log2(numeric_limits<decltype(numbers)::key_type>::max()));

generate(int_log.begin(), int_log.end(), []{static auto i = 0; return 1 << ++i;});

auto maximum = 0u;

for_each(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), [&](auto i){unsigned int index = log2(i); maximum = max(maximum, index); int_log[index] = min(int_log[index], i);});

for_each(int_log.begin(), next(int_log.begin(), maximum + 1), [](auto i){cout << i << endl;});
```

There are two things that I'd like to accomplish:

1. Have elements of `int_log` initialize themselves to the correct value according to their index.
2. Only create the elements as that I need, rather than all possible elements up front.

The only solutions I'm thinking of for these questions are very involved `map` or `set` containers. Can someone give me a simpler solution?